# Android studio - gradle 4.1.1 - minsdk 23 : Exception when using "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary" on android device 6.0.1

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

Good morning,

I have exception when using "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary" on android device 6.0.1

- gradle version 4.1.1
- minsdkVersion : android 6 (23)
- using appcompat-v7:27.1.1
- I replace app:src by app:srcCompat

I insert 2 SVG file : activate_identification_mode.svg and deactivate_identification_mode.svg using android vector asset tools

When building code and install on android 7 and 8 devices, no problem.

When install application on android 6.0.1 device => exception crash

```
12-21 10:53:55.631 13358-13358/eu.sprinte.swift E/VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating <vector>
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/$activate_identification_mode__0.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f080000
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateListForCookie(Resources.java:4336)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:4285)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:441)
        at android.support.v4.content.res.TypedArrayUtils.getNamedColor(TypedArrayUtils.java:124)
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$VFullPath.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:1746)
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat$VFullPath.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:1712)
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflateInternal(VectorDrawableCompat.java:743)
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:631)
        at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:590)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:775)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:363)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:77)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:181)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:105)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:195)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at eu.sprinte.swift.fragments.tools.identification328SP.Step1_activateModeConfig.onCreateView(Step1_activateModeConfig.java:34)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2215)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.o
12-21 10:53:55.641 13358-13358/eu.sprinte.swift E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: eu.sprinte.swift, PID: 13358
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at eu.sprinte.swift.fragments.tools.identification328SP.Step1_activateModeConfig.onCreateView(Step1_activateModeConfig.java:34)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2215)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1238)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1086)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1616)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20166)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20166)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:900)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20166)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20166)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20166)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1632)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20166)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20166)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:900)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20166)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20166)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1059)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20166)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20166)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20166)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChi
```

Can you help me please

Best regards
Loïc